# How to get latest tag from SVN using git svn through shell script

Tags: git, svn, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, git-svn

how to retrieve latest svn tag using git svn client from origin through shell script.

Basically would like to automate getting latest tag from remote SVN and sync with local git repo. So I use "git svn" and would like to introduce hudson/jenkins job to perform this step.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Convert the svn tags to git tags and then use them as you usually.

```
# Loop on all the remote tags 
git-for-each-ref refs/remotes/origin/tags | cut -d / -f 5- | while read ref
do

# Attach the tag to the desired commit
git tag -a "$ref" -m"say farewell to SVN" "refs/remotes/origin/tags/$ref"

# remove the old reference 
git push origin ":refs/heads/tags/$ref"

# push it to your remote so your jenkins can use it
git push origin tag "$ref"

done
```

You can also read about it here as well:
https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-and-Other-Systems-Migrating-to-Git